# XML parsing äöü Java

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I'm programming a program in Java, which is parsing XML. My Problem is, that the special signs like `ä`, `ö`, `ü` aren't show in my application. But the rest of the text yet. Example:

```
Oliver Krähnbühl  => Oliver Krhnbhl
```

I can't do something by the coding of the XML. Because its loaded by HTTP-Request.

Here is the code of the parser:

```
public Boolean parse(String url) {
    try {
        InputStream inStream = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();


        // TODO: after we must do a cache of this XML!!!!
        this.factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        this.builder = this.factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        this.builder.isValidating();
        Document doc = this.builder.parse(inStream, null);

        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        //Get all categories
        NodeList categoryList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Category");

        //Loop each category
        for (int i = 0; i < categoryList.getLength(); i++) {
            //Get categoryname
            final NamedNodeMap attr     = categoryList.item(i).getAttributes();
            final String categoryName   = getNodeValue(attr, "name");

            //Add a category separator
            productSeparator s = new productSeparator(categoryName);
            this.list.add(s);

            //Get current Category as element
            Element category        = (Element)categoryList.item(i);

            //Get all Products from current category
            NodeList productList    = category.getElementsByTagName("Product");

            //Loop each element from each category
            for(int x = 0; x < productList.getLength(); x++)
            {
                //Get current Product as element
                Element product     = (Element)productList.item(x);

                //Set properties to variable

                String productName          = (((Element)product.getElementsByTagName("Name").item(0)).getChildNodes()).item(0).getNodeValue();
                String productDescription   = (((Element)product.getElementsByTagName("Description").item(0)).getChildNodes()).item(0).getNodeValue();
                String productPrice         = (((Element)product.getElementsByTagName("Price").item(0)).getChildNodes()).item(0).getNodeValue();
                String productImageUri      = (((Element)product.getElementsByTagName("ImageUri").item(0)).getChildNodes()).item(0).getNodeValue();

                // Construct Country object
                product p = new product(productName, productDescription, new Float(productPrice), productImageUri);

                // Add to list
                this.list.add(p);
            }
        }
        return true;
    } 
    catch (Exception er) {
        Log.e("Exception", er.toString());
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Without seeing the XML (and its encoding), the code parsing it, and the code displaying it, it will be hard to answer.

Comment: That's weird. It works in my app. Maybe you should post your code that parses the XML document and displays it.

Comment: Can you show us the code where you set up the parsing from the HTTP response? Also, can you confirm whether the string is actually missing characters? Perhaps it's just a display issue.

Comment: How are you parsing the xml? How is the code "loaded via HTTP Request"? Only with all these details we can say why `ä` becomes `a`.

Comment: If you are using servlet to get the HTTP request, you can use this: `request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8")` and then get the stream...

Comment: Could we see the display code too? My intuition is that the bug would be there, since special characters are disappearing.

Answer (score 3):

did you try to use a input stream reader?

something like:

```
Reader reader 
   = new InputStreamReader((InputStream) new URL(url).getContent(), "utf-8");
```

and use a [StreamSource](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/stream/StreamSource.html) or [InputSource](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/xml/sax/InputSource.html) to create the XML, something like:

```
InputSource src = new InputSource(reader);
Document doc = this.builder.parse(src);
```

also take a look on your output method, for example try this:

```
try
{
  // output to the console
  Writer w =
     new BufferedWriter
        (new OutputStreamWriter(System.out, "utf-8"));
  w.write("looks good: äöü\n"); // looks good
  w.flush();

  w = new BufferedWriter
         (new OutputStreamWriter(System.out, "Cp850"));
  w.write("looks bad: äöü"); // looks bad
  w.flush();
  w.close();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: The server should either send a content-type header specifying the encoding or the parser should determine it by looking at the first few characters and the xml prolog. Hardcoding utf-8 in this case is simply wrong.

Comment: @Jorn Agreed, but overall the answer is helpful - so I'm up-voting.